# What does this mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, downsampling

I have came about a `MATLAB` code like the following:

```
xyz = imfilter(A,B);
xyz_subsample = xyz(1:2:size(xyz, 1), 1:2:size(xyz, 2));
```

The code is related to `subsampling`. But, what does the second line mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second line is taking every second sample in each spatial dimension. So it's downsampling by a factor of 2 in each dimension.

Downsampling should be preceded by lowpass filter in order to avoid aliasing effects. The filter in the first line probably does that. Is `B` a lowpass mask?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, `B` is a lowpass filter

Answer (score 2):

The second line uses the [colon](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator to select every second row and every second colum, which means that every 4th pixel is selected.